# Proof for multiplication of two power series

Tags: real-analysis, summation, power-series

Prove that $(\sum_{k=0}^\infty u^k)^2=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)u^k$ when |u|<1.

This is a proof I need for a larger proof I was doing. I am stuck on this, so I was not able to make any notable attempt.

If possible, I wonder if the proof can try not to use taylor series, so it can blend well in the larger proof I am working on.

Comment: What can you use? Sum of a geometric series, the binomial theorem, differentiation...?

Comment: differentiation can be used for sure. maybe also not using geometric sum formula. I am not very familiar with binomial theorem.

Comment: One way is to take $1+u+u^2+u^3+u^4$ and square it, but look only at the terms of degree $\le4$. You should see then what’s happening, and be able to construct a proof, probably with some elements of mathematical induction in it.

Comment: This is an Arithmetico-Geometric Series. See my solution here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1223811/proof-of-sum-results/1224194#1224194

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The left side is $\frac{1}{(1-u)^2}$ using the geometric series.  The right side is $\frac{d}{du} \frac{1}{1-u}$ if you differentiate the geometric series term by term.

Alternatively, write the left side as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{l=0}^\infty u^{k+l}$ and count the number of terms with $k+l$ equal to a given value $n$, from $(k=0, l=n)$ to $(k=n,l=0)$.  This gives the factor $n+1$ in the summand on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Similar method to Chris , but also try this way
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(u^{k}\right)=\frac{1}{1-u}$$
For $-1<u<1$
This is the property of a geometric series as k approaches $\infty$
Using this property we have ,
$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(u^{k}\right)\right)^{2}=\frac{1}{(1-u)^{2}}$$
Given this properties, and when we derivate$\frac{1}{1-u}$ we get $$\frac{1}{(1-u)^{2}}$$ using properties of derivation( I skipped the derivation part as exersise for you )
Now, the next thing is dervating the sum $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}u^{k}$$ which we can derivate term by term since it is a power series and the radius of convergence stays the same.therefore $$\frac{d}{du} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}u^{k}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{d}{du}\left(u^{k}\right)$$
$=>$

$$\frac{d}{du} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}u^{k}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}ku^{k-1}$$ which is found by listing a few terms and finding a formula or by direct use of property of derivation. $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}ku^{k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)u^{k}$$ by simply avoiding the term 0. consequently we have, 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)u^{k}=\frac{d}{du} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}u^{k}\right)=\frac{d}{du}\left(\frac{1}{1-u}\right)=\frac{1}{(1-u)^{2}}=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}u^{k}\right)^{2}$$
And thus proving the expression. I hope this helps you a bit.